# How to stop activity indicator view?

Tags: iphone, gdata-api, uiactivityindicatorview

I am facing problem to stop the activity indicator view once it starts. I am using action sheet to send the request which fetch data from a requested url and in the mean time of fetching it takes time to load data. Meanwhile activity indicator is used to show the progress of loading. When data is fetched and loaded activity indicator view should stop. Here i am not using web view but Gdata for parsing.

My code looks like this:

```
 -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    //Code for parsing and loading data using gdata parser

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come to the solution by using the instance method of action sheet where stopAnimating message should be used.

```
    -(void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
          [activityIndicator stopAnimating]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Satish,

When this method execute at that time, your both(startAnimating and stopAnimating) of your method are executed so you can`t show the effect of indicator. Check by debugging.

if you req. such things then call startAnimation in separate thread in backGround so you get effect. and stop that after complete your parsing.

Comment: But what is wrong to use in the same method. Here data parsing will be done. So before it start parsing activity indicator is used and when parsing is done stopAnimating message is passed.

Comment: @Satish you check that with debugging. all process done on main thread so you can`t see the UI effect at same time...and when your execution complete at that time both method going to call so u got nothing... on UI